# Android ContextMenu line-break for too long items

Tags: android, line-breaks, android-contextmenu

I implemented a contextMenu (LongClick) and i now experience that one item-text is too long (especially on smaller displays and in other languages) and so you won't be able to read the whole item-text.

Is it possible to do a line-break for that item? Do i have to write my own ContextMenu-Class, or is there an easier way?
I tried to find an answer for a longer period, but didn't find anything.

This is how i create the ContextMenu:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.listView1) {

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Title");
        String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.context_menu_list);
        for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the context_menu_list in strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="context_menu_list">
    <item>Item1</item>
    <item>Item2</item>
    <item>Much too long item to be visible in one line</item>
</string-array>
```

Thanks for any help! If there are any questions: just ask!

Comment: Did you succeed solving this?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't. As I read about this, you should take care to make it short :-\

Comment: I see. In the end, I've made my own dialog that supports multi-line. It takes more code, but it works...

Comment: Yeah of course. I think it is really strange that android hasn't something to help out of this situation (a button to extend the text or something similar would do it). I mean it's ok not to break design-rules (like multiple lines won't be necessary on larger screens), but there should be a way to read all the text. Scrollable text-fields would be sufficient too.